# Store NaN values in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'd like to insert NaN values into SQLite database.

I have Ent table with Id, StringColumn and DoubleColumn (not nullable) and I try use the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Ent (Id, StringColumn, DoubleColumn) VALUES (1, 'NaN test', ????)
```

I don't know what to put in place of '????' to have NaN stored.

I'm accessing the database using System.Data.SQLite - maybe this also matters?

Comment: You could use NULL instead? That would serve a similar purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've asked guys of SQLite how to deal with the problem: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/e06c4caff3c433c80616ae5c6df63fc830825e59. 
They've added a new connection flag: "GetAllAsText" and now it is possible to store NaN, along with the others (Infinity, -Infinity).

Answer (score 5):

SQLite is rather... lax... about data types.  Feel free to put "NaN" into a column defined as "double".  Or "infinity".  Or "double", for that matter.  SQLite doesn't care.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite does not have a textual representation of NaN values.

In SQL, the special `NULL` behaves similarly in computations, and can serve the same purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.
I've tried to use null in this case, but I get error "Abort due to constraint violation. Ent.DoubleColumn may not be NULL". The only way to get it working is to change DoubleColumn to nullable.

Answer (score 2):

The trick that I currently employ is to store -Infinity on Real columns when null won't suffice or is not allowed (since you have "not null" on that column).